# How to use one liner instead of 'for loop ' which also contains if-else statement (example given)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, one-liner

```
if type(prevtag_pair) == list:
    word_tag=[]
    for row in prevtag_pair:
        c =0
        x =[]
        for col in row:
            y=[]
            for pair in col: 
                if len(pair[1])> 0:
                    y.append(pair[0]+ '_'+pair[1])
                else: 
                    y.append(pair[0]+ '_' )
            x.append(y)
        word_tag.append(x)
```

I want to convert it in a one liner. But I am getting error. any help would be appreciated.

```
if type(prevtag_pair) == list:
    word_tag = [[y.append(pair[0]+ '_'+pair[1]) if len(pair[1])> 0 else y.append(pair[0]+ '_' ) ] for row in prevtag_pair for col in row for pair in col]
```

Please correct it iff possible. Thank you.

I/P DATA:

> [[[['challenge', 'D'],    ['opportunity', 'D'],    ['overcoming',
> 'P'],    ['challenge', 'D'],    ['opportunity', 'D'],    ['higher',
> 'D'],    ['levelthan', 'A']],   [['country', 'D'],    ['face', 'P'],
> ['levels', 'N'],    ['challenges', 'A'],    ['democracy', 'A'],
> ['foundational', 'P'],    ['progress', 'A']],   [['challenges', 'A'],
> ['democracy', 'P'],    ['faces', 'N'],    ['world', 'D'],    ['level',
> 'A']],   [['challenge', 'D'],    ['opportunity', 'D'],    ['progress',
> 'A'],    ['statement', 'D'],    ['reveals', 'N'],    ['idea', 'D'],
> ['challenge', 'D'],    ['difficulty', 'D'],    ['hardship', 'A'],
> ['opportunity', 'D'],    ['progress', 'A'],    ['challenge', 'D'],
> ['overcome', 'A'],    ['challenge', 'D'],    ['succeed', 'P'],
> ['overcoming', 'A'],    ['rise', 'A'],    ['higher', 'D'],
> ['level', 'A'],    ['progess', 'A']],   [['challenges', ['o']],
> ['enlight', 'N'],    ['deal', 'P'],    ['ways', 'D'],    ['like',
> 'A'],    ['obstacles', 'A'],    ['enlights', 'P'],    ['afford', 'P'],
> ['best', 'P'],    ['result', 'D'],    ['challenges', 'P'],    ['like',
> 'A'],    ['opportunity', 'D'],    ['progress', 'P'],    ['want', 'P'],
> ['deal', 'P'],    ['smartly', 'P'],    ['victorious', 'V'],
> ['looser', 'C'],    ['life', 'P']],   [['challenge', 'D'],
> ['problem', 'D'],    ['opportunity', 'D'],    ['progress', 'A'],
> ['meansa', 'N'],    ['challenge', 'P'],    ['problem', 'D'],
> ['help', 'D'],    ['development', 'D'],    ['ex', 'P'],    ['farmer',
> 'D'],    ['challenging', 'A'],    ['grow', 'P'],    ['plants', 'A'],
> ['set', 'P'],    ['target', 'P'],    ['help', 'V'],    ['development',
> 'A']]]]

O/P: error is coming as    [none],[none],.....

Comment: Could you please add the error?

Comment: Can you also add the variable datatypes or provide some mock data?

Comment: there comes a point where condensing something in a list comprehension does not make sense any more. Your code snippet with a three nested `for` loops and an `if-else` statement is way beyond that point in my opinion.. There is no strict rule here, but I would only do it for the last (innermost) `for` loop. You are sacrificing too much readability otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might solve your problem,

```
for row in prevtag_pair:
    word_tag = [[f'{pair[0]}_{pair[1]}' if len(pair[1]) > 0 else f'{pair[0]}_' for pair in col] for col in row ]
    print(word_tag)
```

**Output:**

```
[['challenge_D', 'opportunity_D', 'overcoming_P', 'challenge_D', 'opportunity_D', 'higher_D', 'levelthan_A'], ['country_D', 'face_P', 'levels_N', 'challenges_A', 'democracy_A', 'foundational_P', 'progress_A'], ['challenges_A', 'democracy_P', 'faces_N', 'world_D', 'level_A'], ['challenge_D', 'opportunity_D', 'progress_A', 'statement_D', 'reveals_N', 'idea_D', 'challenge_D', 'difficulty_D', 'hardship_A', 'opportunity_D', 'progress_A', 'challenge_D', 'overcome_A', 'challenge_D', 'succeed_P', 'overcoming_A', 'rise_A', 'higher_D', 'level_A', 'progess_A'], ["challenges_['o']", 'enlight_N', 'deal_P', 'ways_D', 'like_A', 'obstacles_A', 'enlights_P', 'afford_P', 'best_P', 'result_D', 'challenges_P', 'like_A', 'opportunity_D', 'progress_P', 'want_P', 'deal_P', 'smartly_P', 
'victorious_V', 'looser_C', 'life_P'], ['challenge_D', 'problem_D', 'opportunity_D', 'progress_A', 'meansa_N', 'challenge_P', 'problem_D', 'help_D', 'development_D', 'ex_P', 'farmer_D', 'challenging_A', 'grow_P', 'plants_A', 'set_P', 'target_P', 'help_V', 'development_A']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
word_tag = [[[f'{pair[0]}_{pair[1]}' if len(pair[1]) > 0 else f'{pair[0]}_' for pair in col] for col in row ]for row in prevtag_pair]
```

This works good!

@Nanthakumar J J: Many thanks...

Comment: @ Ma0: Thank you for your kind suggestion. Actually my data is as big as 50gb. That is why I am trying to reduce runtime of each and every line possible.